# Sencha Touch: Any event which is fired after List Items have been rendered

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, datalist, sencha-touch-2.3

Simple problem but I haven't managed to find a possible solution:

I have a list in Sencha Touch with Items generated through the `itemTpl` property.
Now I want to go through the items (after they were rendered!) in the DOM and Replace their images (using imgCache for on-device-caching of images)

The `Painted` event of the List doesn't help because it's fired before the Item-DOM is rendered.

EDIT:
My current solution is to override the internal `updateListItem` method of the `Ext.dataview.List`, call the original `updateListItem` there and add there my additional functionality. Still looking for a better solution ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list associated store's `load` event is what you're looking for.

[EDIT]

As you point out in the comments the `load` event is not guaranteed to be thrown after the items have actually been rendered.

I think your approach is correct, but instead of adding in place your functionality, why don't you fire a custom event at the end of the overridden method, passing the list item itself, so that you can listen for that event on the list?

Something like:

```
updateListItem: function(item, index, info) {

    // function body ...

    me.fireEvent('listitemupdate', [item, index]);

}
```

That should keep your code a little more clean and reusable.

Comment: The load event is called after the store was loaded... at this moment the DOM of the List is empty.

Comment: I'm going to look into it, but it works for me for similar tasks. Did you try it? Are you sure the list component is not kept in sync *before* firing load on the store?

Comment: Yeah i tried it... i just added a "alert(document.getElementById('DOM_ID_OF_THE_LIST').innerHTML)" and that retrieves a null reference error. Based on the documentation the store -load- event is called when the store has successfully loaded, not when the DataList was rendered...

Comment: I'll investigate on this, I'm curious why it's working for me and not for you. By the way, I would suggest answering your own question instead of writing your solution as an edit.

Comment: Okay, thx, I'm also curious... And about the answering: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking" ;)

Comment: have you been able to find out something?

Comment: I have studied `Ext.dataview.Dataview`, `Ext.dataview.List` and `Ext.data.Store` source code and I understand that you are right on the `Store` load event being not directly related to the rendering of items. For some reason it was working for me, but we shouldn't rely on that. I am updating my answer with a suggestion for a slightly better approach starting from yours.

Comment: I'll accept your answer. But I don't get it why there is no regular way of doing this... it's for me a function I need a lot, for example if you have a list with cached images. Caching usually works asynchronous and you have to somehow trigger this loading.

Comment: That is a good question for Sencha's developers. I think it worses performances, that is probably the reason they didn't implement it.

Comment: That that's maybe the reason. The list is anyway unbearable slow on the android devices... but that's another story.